# AS3 is entering on a non-true if

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, video-streaming

I'm writting a little plugin for the LongtailVideo JW Player, it's AS3. I got a listener that gets the current playtime and a Timer() that counts the seconds the video has played (I start-stop the Time() on buffers, pause...)

The thing is, I need to fire another event once the time played reaches 30s, so I'm using the listener that gets the playtime (is fired constantly) and I'm checking if the Timer()'s value is 30 or not, if it's I'll do my thing, if its not, nothing.

This is the code snippet:

```
    private function countCheck(event:MediaEvent):void {            
        if(timeCounter.currentCount == 30){
            ExternalInterface.call( "console.log" , "Time elapsed " + timeCounter.currentCount );
        }
    }
```

`timeCounter` has been declared as timer and it's working alright, the thing is, that it enters that if (and displays the log) even if the `timeCounter.currentCount` is not 30, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong!

This is the console output:

```
Time elapsed 0
Time elapsed 0
Time elapsed 30 (5x)
```

I don't mind the repetitions once I reach 30, as I can add a flag and do the action only once.

Any thoughts?

EDIT: I recompiled using Flash CS4 and it's working fine, weird. I think Christophe Herreman was right, and changing the environment changed the cache, so it worked.

Comment: Based on your console output, is it jumping from 0, 0, 30?  Have you tried running the debugger from flash and see what it's kicking out?

Comment: To get the debugger I need to install Flash, right? I'm compiling the AS using the Flex SDK. It's entering the if two times on 0, and then again on 30. Sometimes it does the same on 31, it's weird! I'm going to try to get the flash debugger.

Comment: Have you tried to clean your project? It looks like perhaps a cached version of the code is still being ran.

Comment: I think you're right, Crhistophe. I compiled with Flash CS4 instead of using the Flex SDK and worked fine. I just cleaned all the caches on the SDK and its working there too.

Comment: @Christophe: Make your comment an answer, so that @Adirael can accept it to mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to clean your project? It looks like perhaps a cached version of the code is still being ran.

(posting this as an answer after my comment seems to resolve the issue)

Comment: Sorry for all the time it took me to realize you posted your comment as answer!